# How do you selectively migrate Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Given any standard Django `models.py` file, how can you tell Django to include / exclude certain models conditionally (e.g. based on variables in the `settings.py` module) when running `python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]`?

Comment: You can always edit the generated migration and remove any operations for the models you want to exclude

Answer (score 1):

When running `python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]` you cannot exclude certain models. You can write migrations manually, read the documentation: [Writing database migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/writing-migrations/).
Or run `python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]` and then edit the generated migrations file to delete operations that construct models you want to exclude.